# Why does a chained promise's .then() runs after the prior promise failed with .catch()?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have three functions `functionA`, `functionB`, and `functionC`.

Why does the `.then(id)...` block inside `functionC` run even though `functionB` throws an error and ends with the `catch` statement.

I'm sure I'm missing something important about promises.

```
    const functionA = () => {
      return fetch("http://localhost:3001/types")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => data)
        .catch((error) => error);
    };

    const functionB = (type) => {
      return functionA()
        .then((response) => response.filter((item) => item.name === type))
        .then((result) => {
          if (result.length !== 1) { // assume for this example this is truthy
            const error = new Error("no type found or found more than one");
            throw error;
          } else {
            return result[0].id;
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => error); // this runs as expected since we're throwing an error above
    };
    

    const functionC = (x, y) => {                
      return functionB(y)
        .then((id) => { //why does this block run? 
          
                       //..do something
                      })
           
        .catch((error) => console.log("functionB threw an error"));
    };
```

Comment: Exactly *because* you have *caught* the error, which allows the chain to continue successfully.

Comment: Side note: There's never any reason for `.then((data) => data)`. It just introduces an extra async resolution without changing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `catch` handler converts rejection into fulfillment with the `error` value. Just remove the `.catch((error) => error);` entirely, so that the rejection propagates to the caller.

This (which is basically what you have, just spread across two functions):

```
doSomething()
.then(x => { /* ...do something with x...*/ })
.catch(error => error)
.then(y => { /* ...do something with y...*/ });
```

is roughly analogous to this synchronous code:

```
let y;
try {
    const x = doSomething();
    y = /* ...do something with x... */;
} catch (error) {
    y = error;
}
/* ...do something with y... */;
```

Catching the error and then completing normally suppresses the error.

In general, non-`async` code using promises should do one of two things:

1. Handle the error locally — this is usually only top-level entry points like your main function (if you have one) or event handlers.
2. Return the result of calling `then` *without* using `catch`, so that rejections propagate to the outermost level (where, hopefully, they're handled because of #1 above).

FYI, that's basically what `async`/`await` does automatically for you (ignoring a lot of details). Just for what it's worth, here's that code (slightly modified) using `async`/`await`, assuming `functionC` is the top-level entry point where errors should be handled:

```
const functionA = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/types");
    if (!response.ok) { // (You're missing this check)
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
};

const functionB = async (type) => {
    const result = (await functionA()).filter(item => item.name === type);
    if (result.length !== 1) {
        const error = new Error("no type found or found more than one");
        throw error;
    }
    return result[0].id;
};

const functionC = async (x, y) => {
    // I'm assuming this is your top-level entry point, so we'll handle
    // errors here
    try {
        const id = await functionB(y);
        //..do something
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("functionB threw an error");
    }
};
```